# Horizon/RethinkDB/Ionic2 cannot read property "push" of undefined

Tags: ionic2, rethinkdb, horizon

I'm struggling with an error. It tooks me over 2 days and still no solution... 
I'm using Ionic2 as a frontend and Horizon with RethinkDB as a backend. I have a table called 'messages' and few messages in it. I just want to get all these messages and show them on my HomePage. 
Here is my code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

declare var Horizon;


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    test: any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {




  }

  getMessages(){
    let test = [];
    let hz = new Horizon({host: 'localhost:3100'});
    hz.connect();
    let messages = hz('messages');
    messages.watch().subscribe(messages => {
        for(let i = 0; i<messages.length; i++){
                console.log(messages[i].text);
                console.log(messages[i].id);
            this.test.push([{
                text: messages[i].text,
                id: messages[i].id
            }])
        }
    });
  }

}
```

I tried with many combinations of **this.test.push** but still no luck. I'm doing something wrong... Hope you guys help me!

Comment: This is happening because `this.test` is undefined. This should work if you just use `test.push(...` or change `let test = [];` to `this.test = [];`

Comment: Damn... Everything works now, thank you! I don't know why I didn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem was just ensuring to reference the variable you think you're referencing.

`this.test` *is* undefined. Instead of `let test = [];` you should change it to `this.test = [];`.

Or you can change `this.test.push(...` to `test.push(...` and it should also work fine.

Being cautious when using `this` and juggling scope in Javascript is one of the trickiest parts of the language. I wish there was some indicator in the error as to what part in the chain is actually `undefined` as you thought `.push` was `undefined` on `this.test` where actually it was `test` which was undefined on the `this` object.